# How much (self) editing is too much?

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

*(N.B. not to be confused with [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1880/1543))*

We are all aware of editing being a core value of [the part-Wiki nature](https://math.stackexchange.com/about) of the Stack Exchange websites.

We are also all aware of the website providing a system of check-and-balances for edits, as a way to prevent and counteract intentional vandalism or spam content. One of the most prominent of this aspect is that every time and question or an answer is edited, and every time a question is re-tagged, the software 'bumps' the question up to the top of the list of "Active" questions.

To prevent a user from using the above safety check as a method of keeping a question constantly on the front page (and presumably earn more reputation from the increased exposure), a secondary rule is in place that a post when edited too-much (by too many editors or by the original poster 10 or more times) becomes automatically Community Wiki. One can think of this as a way of reducing the likelihood of gaming the system.

Now, **given the above check-and-balances (which I think takes pretty good care of the technical and reputation aspect of the problem), is there any other reason why we should discourage "frequent and plenty" (*see below the cut*) edits?**

One possible objection I can see that may be raised is that "repeated edits crowd the front page and reduces the visibility of other questions". Some may counter that the existence of the "Newest" page in the list of questions should amend that. But for better or for worse recall that the default front-page to a first time user is the "Active" page.

---

*For the sake of argument, let us define "frequent and plenty" thus:* imagine a user who decides, for whatever reason, to write his or her response piecemeal, adding to it with a new edit every half hour, over the period of say 8 hours. (So 16 edits to the post in one working day.)

*Further clarification*: this question is **not** about the occasional bug fix; nor is it about discouraging edits in the abstract. It is only about **a large  number of edits** coming in **a short period of time**. To phrase it differently: given that the software already "penalizes" (for the lack of a better word) a user for doing too many edits, is it then ok for a user to knowingly make "frequent and plenty" (see above) edits provided he/she is willing to "pay the tax" (so to speak)?

Comment: I am reminded of one user who composed his *comments* highly piecemeal (because he refused to type Shift-Enter vs. Enter for newlines). It seems we didn't handle that situation optimally, since we lost a valued member. Hopefully, with further experience, we now can do better.

Comment: I personally think the threshold for converting to CW is probably a little high. I think 6-7 is a little better range. The rep-hunting behavior is somewhat noticeable on this site, on occasion, but can be *very* obtrusive on sites with lower traffic. At any rate, I've observed people getting around *that* (once they've had a post or two CW-hammered and realized why it has happened) by making piddly edits to the question or, even, to other answers. So, there is probably no way to address this completely.

Comment: And, just for the sake of irony, I should note that it took four edits to my comment before I got it to read (more or less) the way I wanted it to.

Comment: @cardinal I'm a newbie here. Could you explain what you mean by "CW-hammered"? I know CW means community wiki, but I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Just that, after 10 self edits, your post *automatically* becomes community wiki, meaning, among other things that any further votes on your post will not affect your reputation (positively or negatively).

Comment: @cardinal Does that mean that votes will not be shown on my post anymore?

Comment: @Makoto: No. Votes will still show next to your post as they continue to accumulate, you just won't see your reputation change due to any new votes. See the FAQ and SO meta regarding CW for more info.

Comment: @cardinal Thanks.

Comment: @MakotoKato You can read about this in the following question and the questions linked to it: [Why my questions were turned into community wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/why-my-questions-were-turned-into-community-wiki).

Comment: It also means that the threshold for editing by others is lowered. It only takes 100 reputation to be able to edit a CW post, regardless of who made it, but it takes twenty times as much, 2000, to edit other people's posts.

Comment: @MakotoKato: How come you haven't registered?

Comment: I fear an outcome similar to the one Bill pointed out in the first comment, especially in view of the downvotes/comments in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170234/nilpotency-of-the-jacobson-radical-of-an-artinian-ring-without-axiom-of-choice).

Comment: Please see my answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4660/6622).

Comment: Of course this question's main target is me. However, the main person(Asaf Karagila) who is complaining to me has never mentioned the problem, if any, of crowded front page of this site. Apparently his reason is elsewhere.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Will there be any problem if I don't register?

Comment: @MakotoKato: Registration shows a certain amount of commitment to the community. It makes your user page searchable in the "Users" interface. Mostly, though, it shows your willingness to be *part* of the community, something that from where I'm standing you have never actually shown any desire to do, so in retrospect I'm not surprised you haven't. And I asked **you** why you haven't registered; if you don't wish to respond, don't, but don't evade it and throw the question back at me.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for answering me.
"Mostly, though, it shows your willingness to be part of the community, something that from where I'm standing you have never actually shown any desire to do, so in retrospect I'm not surprised you haven't." I wonder why you think I've never shown any desire to show my willingness to be part of the community. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "if you don't wish to respond, don't, but don't evade it and throw the question back at me."
I'm a newbie here.
I just didn't know if there would be any problem if I don't register.
So I didn't think I could aswer your question properly.
So I asked you.
If I hurt your feeling by asking it, I'm awfully sorry.
Please forgive me. Regards.

Comment: @MakotoKato: You've been active for 3 months, with 35 answers (some lengthy), and over 1000 actions. It's rather disingenous to call yourself a "newbie", and if you don't know, it's because you refuse to listen. It's not about "hurting my feelings"; frankly, I find that kind of condescension annoying (not "hurt feelings", just plain annoyance). And from where I'm standing, the rest of your comment sounds so over the top and disingenuous that it's equally irritating, as is your general attitude in this forum.

Comment: @MakotoKato: You have dismissed any and all attempts at engaging you in dialogue, demanding instead that people "explain to you" what they have already explained, dismissing any opposite view or consensus as "just" opinion, misrepresented what others say; and after three months and over a thousand actions, you have, as is **evidenced by your very question in this comment thread** made absolutely **no** effort to learn the ways of the community, instead searching only for arguments to justify your behaviour when others try to call attention to why it may not be welcome. (cont)

Comment: @MakotoKato: If you can't see how this looks like a lack of desire to become part of the community, then your social graces are rather deficient. I also find the continual insistence that others have to spell out everything for you in detail, several times, only to have you dismiss them later irritating, and yet another example of how you show absolutely no effort to become part of the community, prefering instead to **use** the community to your own ends. And that's it, I have no desire to communicate further with you, especially since I expect all your replies to this to be self-serving.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I really didn't/don't know what kind of problem would there be if I don't register.
Yes, I posted several answers(I don't count how many), but that doesn't necessarily mean I should know the answer of my question regarding registration.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin As for your other comments, there has been no consensus so far about whether what I'm doing should be stopped or not. We are arguing on it.
Just because you have an opinion against me does not necessarily mean it is a public one.

Comment: @MakotoKato: And there you go with the self-serving misrepresentations. We are arguing about it **because you refuse to listen to anyone other than yourself**, and you **refuse** to consider anybody but yourself. You have absolutely no interest in being part of the community; your only interest is to **use** the community to your own ends and your own ends only. You dismiss everything you don't agree with, and repeat over and over and over irrelevant mantras as if that excuses you. It doesn't. Don't ping me again. I have no interest in reading your self-serving excuses for your lack of manners

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Since I became a member, I have posted several questions and answers, some of which I think are interesting for a mathematics community. In short, I think I'm contributing to this site if not greatly. I have no idea why you think I don't have any desire to be a part of this community just because I didn't register. Again, would there be any problem If I don't register? I'm just asking. I'm not implying that the regisration is unimportant.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "Your only interest is to use the community to your own ends and your own ends only." How did I use the community to my own ends only by answering the questions of other members?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You seem to think answering my own question is using the community for my own ends only. This is not true, either. Actually answering one's own question is being encouraged by this site.

Comment: I wonder why some people are objecting fiercely against "blogging" or "publishing". Maybe they are in a wrong place: "Since Stack Overflow launched, we've been trying to explain that it's not just a Q&A platform: it's also a place where you can publish things that you've learned: recipes, FAQs, HOWTOs, walkthroughs, and even bits of product documentation, as long you format it as a question and answer." http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange

Comment: If there will be a rule regarding frequent edits, of course, I'll follow it.
However, if the rule is too strict, it is very likely that I will never post an answer like this:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56454/abelian-categories-and-axiom-ab5/

Comment: @MakotoKato: And, yet again, you *pretend* that this is about you "answering your own questions." It's about your **general behavior**. I repeat the simile that was done before: people are not objecting to you cutting your steak, which you like to pretend they are. We are objecting to you continually stabbing cows. Now, do me a favor and stop insulting my intelligence by pretending to be clueless. You are not, and it wore thin a long time ago. At this point, you are just being insulting. Let me also point out that while several threads have been started discussing **your** behavior (cont)

Comment: @MakotoKato: **none** have been started discussing mine. If that were not evidence that you are behaving well outside the norm, then what is? Oh, right. We are just "discusssing" it. No. We aren't. We are trying to tell you that you are behaving in a way that the at least a large portion of the community finds objectionable, **as is evidenced by continuing discussions about your behavior in meta.** People don't object to blogging, they object to you using this site as your personal blog. People don't object to users answering their own questions, they object to *how* **YOU** do it.

Comment: @MakotoKato: It's amazing how much you can find and quote in the FAQ for self-serving purposes, while at the same time pretending that you don't know about registering, you don't know about community standards, etc. I say again: that can only be because you **don't want** to know, because you have reckless disregard for others. "Maybe you are in the wrong place." Amazing, then, how nobody makes long threads about my behavior, but they do about yours. And I tell you again: don't ping me (don't reply to me, don't `@Arturo` me). At this point, I'm done with you insulting my intelligence.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*(Note: People in chat have pointed out to me that this meta question might have been an attempt to continue a comment discussion from [this mainsite post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168009/lying-over-theorem-without-axiom-of-choice/168083#168083) -- at least Willie pointed the particpants in that question to this one, and it certainly appears that those participants want this meta question to be about whether that particular user's editing patterns are acceptable or not. However, my answer here is an answer to the general question Willie actually asked: Is there a reason to discourage users in general from making many edits to a post over a short time, on the grounds solely that the number of edits is too large, and independently of their content?)*

---

If the "frequent and plenty" edits actually make the post better, then the only problem I can see they create is the frontpage bumping. This problem should not be solved by discouraging the improving of posts; see below. On the other hand, edits that make the post *worse* should be discouraged no matter if there are only one of them. For *both* kinds of edits, their absolute number is irrelevant.

I fairly frequently amend my answers as I find simpler way to explain or define things or am reminded of considerations I should have taken into account in the first place. I also routinely edit my answers to fix typos and bad prose, because I want my answer to be the best possible answer I can provide.

I don't recall that I've ever hit the CW limit with this, but I still think it would be bad to actively discourage edits. The alternative would be to advise users *either* to leave improvable answers in a non-improved state, *or* to sit on an unsubmitted answer until they were 100% certain that they couldn't possibly ever find a way to improve it. Neither of these would be beneficial to our primary mission of providing high-quality answer in a timely and helpful manner. (The latter outcome would be harmful through duplication of effort; it would cause a much larger risk of writing the same answer that someone else has already completed and is just setting aside on the off chance that he would find a way to improve it before finally submitting).

I can see that a stream of rep-farming inconsequential edits can be annoying, but I think a better fix for that would be to tweak the bumping algorithm. For example, there could be a rule in the software that edits from a single user cannot cause a post to be bumped more than once every 10 hours (for some appropriate value of 10). Then if one edited the post quickly after having bumped it once, the bumping would simply be deferred until 10 hours after the last bump.

That way, monopolizing the front page would be harder, but self-vandalism edits would still be caught eventually. Classic drive-by vandalism of a post that haven't been edited for a while would be caught immediately, just like with the current behavior, because the bump would only be deferred if there had been a bump recently.

Comment: Henning, suggesting someone to prepare their own answers **before** posting is not discouraging edits. As you said, you have never hit CW. Why? Because you did not post your answer in tiny parts, piece by piece. If your post had reached **80** edits then something is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Asaf: We should optimize for the common case, not for extremes. If we tell people not to make so many edits, what this will lead to in the common case is just answers that are not as good as they could have been. _Especially_ if the common case is not one that really needs that admonishment.

Comment: No, one should aim for the common case, but deal with extremities. We always tend to assume that there is a common intersection in the common sense of everyone using the software, but from time to time we see that this is not the case: e.g. when a user fails to see why people have problems with him consistently using MSE as a scratchpad. Have I ever done that? No, and I wrote some damn long answer. Neither have you, Arturo, or any other user until now. Saying "It is okay to discipline your kid" does not imply "It is okay to beat him with a bull whip", for most people but sometimes...

Comment: @Asaf: The fact that there may be _a few_ people who use the software in one unreasonable way does in no way justify encouraging _everybody_ to use it in a _different_ suboptimal way. The benefit of possibly getting a few users to abuse the system less is far outweighed by the damage it would do to tell everybody to limit their editing. It has enormous _negative_ net benefit.

Comment: But this entire discussion is exactly about how much is too much. Do you think that keeping one euro you found on the street is morally justified? What about two, five, ten, fifty, a dufflebag full of blood money and cocaine? What if there was no cocaine in the bag? There is a point where social norm dictates that you cannot keep the money. The discussion here is about this social norm with respect to edits. No one discourages edits, we just want to figure out when is the point where a user should first work out the answer off-site and *then* post it in a single edit.

Comment: @Asaf: And my contribution to the discussion is that I think that a social norm that discourages edits is actually harmful for the site and we shouldn't have one. If many edits creates a technical problem, then that ought to receive a technical fix, not by instituting a social norm that works around the technical problem by crippling the _core function_ of the site.

Comment: **But for the love of Godel** no one is discouraging edits!!! When you give a lecture in a topic you have not taught before and only know in general details, do you prepare yourself or do you begin studying in class? The former is an extremely bad form of teaching. In fact we **should** discourage people writing answers in parts. If you want to write an answer, just write it **off the site** in case it takes you too much time. Do you have any idea how many files I have in my Dropbox filled with half-answers?? What if I were to post them all and then edit them through the day?

Comment: @Asaf: **WHAT WE ARE DISCUSSING HERE** is Willie's question **whether it is a good idea to discourage edits** that do not yet rise to the level where the CW-hammer sets in. I am answering that question in the negative. If you want to discuss something else than Willie's proposal, I suggest you do it in another thread

Comment: Then we are reading into two different questions.

Comment: @Asaf: Willie's question, in boldface, says "is there any other reason why we should discourage 'frequent and plenty' edits?"

Comment: @Mark: What is frequent and plenty is part of the discussion. There is absolutely no one on this site, I hope, that thinks that discouraging editing and improving a post is a good idea. However the reason this whole thread came up was due to a user using MSE as a scratchpad instead of preparing posts off-site. I don't see why is it so horrific to accept a social norm of people doing most of the editorial work **before** clicking "Post Answer". Maybe I'm just missing something...

Comment: And yes, it bothers me when someone is making 30 or more edits to their posts, even more when it happens in a couple of days. Just like it would bother me to hear from a friend that they found a briefcase full of money and decided to keep it for themselves.

Comment: @Asaf, I wonder if you know this story about the American baseball player, Yogi Berra. He was asked what he would do if he found a million dollars on the street. He said that if the guy who lost it was real poor, he'd give it back to him.

Comment: @Gerry: What if all the money I have is a million dollars? Losing it made me real poor... I wonder what he would have done with a briefcase full of money *and* drugs. :-)

Comment: @Mark: what I wrote was "... 'frequent and plenty' (see below) edits", with the definition of 'frequent and plenty' given below the cut. I apologize for not knowing how to make a better footnote.

Comment: @Henning: see my previous comment. I've tried to set the discussion in a frame where the user edited 16 times, which hits the auto-CW. Apparently I didn't make it clear enough. Let me go try to emphasize that.

Comment: @Willie: If each of the 16 edits improved the post, then the only possible problem I see with that is the frontpage bumping. That is a technical problem that ought to be solved technically. On the other hand, if the edits _don't_ improve the post, then even one is too many. It's not just a question of numbers.

Comment: @Henning: But this is really not just black and white. It's not either improve the post or edit 80 times. You can edit the post on your own computer, and then edit it *once* instead.

Comment: Just to clarify [my previous comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/how-much-self-editing-is-too-much#comment17666_4627): in case I wasn't clear about it, it was written to clarify the OP in view of [Mark's comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/how-much-self-editing-is-too-much#comment17658_4627) and [Henning's comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/how-much-self-editing-is-too-much#comment17653_4627). I have not expressed an opinion. I was just hoping to focus the discussion.

Comment: @Asaf: You're assuming that someone who edits a post must have known when he originally submitted it (or when he edited it previously) that he would find an improvement to edit in later. That is, in my experience, essentially never the case. If one had to refrain from submitting because one _might_ discover a possible improvement later, I for one would never get to answer _anything_. The mere _possibility_ of hoarding an unsubmitted post on the off chance that one might later discover a possible improvement to it does not mean that it doing so is desirable. I hold that it is not.

Comment: @Henning: Yes, that is true. If you *don't* know that your answer is incomplete then it is not a real problem. If you post an answer and over the next 30 revisions you keep a notice in the top part "**This answer is incomplete. I will complete it later**", then what you are doing amounts to a misuse of the software.

Comment: @Willie: Even with that clarification, I maintain that if 16 edits in a row all improve the post, then we _should not tell anyone_ that those edits should not have been made. If each of 80 edits in a row all improve the post, then we should not tell anyone that those edits should not have been made. If 2 edits in a row _do not_ improve the post, then we should tell the editor that those edits should not have been made.

Comment: @Asaf: When I post something with "This answer is incomplete" on the top, it is because I have no hope at the time I post it whether I will ever be able to complete it. I'm posting it anyway in the hope that the possible progress it represents will enable someone to break entirely through the problem.

Comment: @Henning: I don't understand why do you object to the idea that MSE is for *answers* and not for *drafts* which you intend to finish. I don't care *at all* for answers that have the title "this answer is incomplete. Please help completing it". I *do* object to someone using this site for something it is not meant for, in my eyes. I could start writing my thesis here, in small parts and a zillion edits. But then again, I have a sense of responsibility and I keep my drafts for myself.

Comment: @Asaf: I don't understand why you think that the number of edits to a post implies anything about whether the original version was a "draft" rather than the poster's best attempt at answering the question. I'm okay with advising people "do not post something where even before you press submit you have concrete updates to it in mind". But that is _independent of_ the number and timing of edits. If you want to discuss a guideline against incremental posting _during_ editing, I suggest doing it in a thread that is not about discouraging "frequent edits" in general, no matter what their motive is.

Comment: Also, even if you post your thesis in a single submit action, that would be just as wrong. MSE is not for the publication of theses, either incrementally or all at once.

Comment: @Henning: The fact that the post contains a title essentially "*This is incomplete and I will take my time over the next few days to edit in more and more changes, as though this is a file on my harddrive, even though it's really not*" is what bothers me.

Comment: It seems to me, my barefooted friend, that you are considering edits and drafting independent, but they are not. If you post a draft answer you are going to edit it more and more and more. The only reason I can think of making *so many* edits is when drafting. Furthermore, in this case the writer **is** acknowledging that this is a partial answer which they intend to complete and add on soon. Even more the problem when the same user informed me in a recent comment conversation that this is a problem they solved and will now post as questions and answers in parts, as it is "too long".

Comment: There is no "this case" we're discussion as far as I'm concerned. I'm answering Willie's question whether we should have a _general_ rule that many edits, in and of themselves, is a problem. We shouldn't.

Comment: @Henning Please see Willie's latest edit. The question was sparked by recent actions of one user. If those actions continue unbridled, then MSE will essentially be used as storage for the rapidly evolving drafts of a book on commutative algebra done constructively (without AC). At least one answer (on AB5) already has over 80 revisions. If even a handful of users did this, editing each post > 20 times per day, then the active questions list would be completely swamped by these users. I see no reason why the edits cannot be coalesced to a few per day - as we all do (with rare exception).

Comment: About five years ago a farmer not far from here killed two thieves that tried to steal his sheep. He was acquitted by a retroactive law which was named (colloquially) after him. There was no "rule" before this mishap, and the debate revolved around the generalization from that particular case. This is the same thing here. One particular user is the first, and maybe one of the few ever, to have used the SE platform like this. Even though the debate is about "a general case", there is really just one case to consider here.

Comment: @Bill: Willie's latest edit does not name or link to any particular case. He asks a _general_ question, and I give a general answer to the question he asks. As for your description of whichever concrete case you and Asaf are talking about, using MSE as a medium for publishing a book on commutative algebra is wrong, no matter how many or how few edits one uses to do so. We don't need any generally applicable discouragement of "too many edits" in order to discourage attempts to use MSE as a book publisher.

Comment: @Henning Yes, I realize that the question was not as precise as it needed to be, so you addressed a matter different than what was intended. Perhaps Willie will clarify it further so that we can get back to the intended query instead of this tangent (though perhaps a new question is needed, since this thread is already derailed due to confusion).

Comment: @Bill and Henning: I deliberately chose not to name names, and tried to follow earlier examples of discussing more generally and abstractly. By pointing the discussion thread on main site here, I was hoping to get multiple points of views on how this _abstract_ question ought to be answered. You can say that this question is _inspired_ by what happened there, but not strictly _tied to_ that discussion. As such, I appreciate Henning's opinion, which answers the question I asked explicitly.

Comment: In view of Asaf's [recent question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4652/1543), one can say that the goal of this question is to seek out opinions as to whether "frequent and plenty" self-edits _in itself_ constitute a misuse of the website. This, of course, only address partially the issue raised by Asaf on the original mains discussion and on that other meta thread. (Part of the reason that I didn't involve the other issues is that I was not sure how to properly describe what happened "in the abstract" without naming names.)

Answer (score 10):

In my view, repeated editing to correct typos, or mathematical mistakes are fine. But at some point the answer should be about done, usually about 5-6 edits, and in some extreme cases 10 edits.

Rarely there is an answer which is edited many times and each edit adds on new information, bibliography and citation (I recall an answer or two of this nature on questions of historical nature).

However writing an answer and editing it 30 or more times simply to expand the proof and add something which results as a piece of lecture notes, or a blog post, this seems unreasonable usage of the software in my eyes. If you wish to work a complete and detailed answer, do it **in advance** rather than during the post itself. I can personally testify working hours and days on some of my answers before posting them.

One other alternative is to write a blog, or actual notes, on the topic and link them in an answer. However simply linking to a blog or notes is itself an unreasonable answer, instead a summary of the argument and a direction towards the complete and detailed topic should be written.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/54562/revisions) is an example of a post, which has many edits, but all those edits are, in my opinion, justified and improved the post.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, this is what I had in mind when I mentioned rare posts where excessive editing is justified.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Could you please explain what is exactly wrong with many(for example 30 revs) edits?

Comment: @Makoto If you continually make edits over short intervals - say every half hour - then your post remains on the front of the *active* questions list the entire day. The small number of front page slots need to be *fairly* shared by all users. Further, we need to keep front-page questions interesting and diverse in order to attract new  experts. Also, if users observe your posts continually bumped for minor edits, they may stop paying attention to your posts, which is probably not what you desire. Better: *coalesce* edits so that you do only one or two a day to a post under active development.

Comment: @BillDubuque I find it strange that nobody has complained to me because of that so far.
As Willie Wong says you can always use the newest page.

Comment: @BillDubuque Anyway I don't think this is a problem because there will be not many people doing such things because people usually care about their reps.

Comment: I find it strange and interesting that some people do care about this seemingly petty issue. I suspect there might be a psycologically interesting phenomenon behind it.

Comment: @Makoto: Do you also find it strange that no one complained on Newton's use of infinitesimals for about a century? It takes time until people notice, and until people show signs of caring about something.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You don't need to care about the issue as I explained.
There will be not many people doing such things.
As for me, I usually don't edit my aswer over 10 times.

Comment: @Makoto: There are not many people who kill their wives and bury their heads in the ground. It still worries me to some extent when these things happen. As for over editing, you have more than one post with that many edits. This *is* something to worry about, at least to some extent.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You've never complained to me because of the crowded active page.
I don't think it's the main reason.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I did it more than one time, but it's far less frequently than otherwise.
And it's only me that doing such things at that time.
So the active page coud not be crowded.
In short, there's nothing for you to worry about.

Comment: @Makoto: I would usually bring out sarcasm, but I already tried that and you took my words literally. The problem is that even if you are the only one who does that, it still may signal people the wrong message on this site. I am not worried about the main page as I am worried about the fact that this is simply not how I see the software intended use.

Comment: @MakotoKato,I have never complained,  but that does not mean that I do not find the behaviour of editing many many times annoying. In fact, I very much do. I have instead opted to simply ignore all your posts. I cannot understand why you cannot do this process of refinement in the cozy privacy of your own computer, sharing with the rest of us the end result, or at least more or less stable and finalized versions—you have surely noticed that you are pretty much the only one using the software in that way...

Comment: @MakotoKato You should just try MO really...... I have even offered to post them on your behalf why not? It seems that the people on Math.SE are not ***competent enough*** to ***answer*** your questions.

Comment: @BenjaLim: Please don't encourage that. I doubt that the competence is what stops people from answering Makoto. Furthermore, it seems that he is trying to prove something very very big and useful for everyone in constructive algebra. **ONCE AGAIN, MAKOTO, PLEASE WRITE IT ON YOUR OWN AND POST IT ON ARXIV.** This site is not your blog, your scratchpad nor it is a platform for publications. Thank you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You misunderstood my comment above.

Comment: @BenjaLim: No, I read it. It says that that I am incompetent in my field of research, and others are incompetent in their field of research, and that the rest of the users are just incompetent in the fields of choice and/or commutative algebra. It also suggests that MO might be a suitable publication model that Makoto is after, let me assure you: it is not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think you took it too literally.....

Comment: @BenjaLim: Trust me, Makoto *cannot* understand sarcasm, he took every word I have ever told him literally. Well, maybe he can, but if he does then he acts the opposite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "This site is not your blog, your scratchpad nor it is a platform for publications."

If you have a public complaint to me, please open a meta thread.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You seem to mix up a problem, if any, of blogging(whatever it is) with a problem, if any, of frequent editing. The two have no relation in principle. Please don't bring two problems at one time.

Comment: @MakotoKato: If you have a problem, please open a meta thread.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm just recommending you to open threads separately. That's for your interest.

Comment: @Makoto: You either misunderstands my point, and that is a big problem - although by the looks of it, it seems that you don't. If you don't misunderstand my point, then what you do here is a clear act of trolling and I will have to ask you to stop.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you bring out the problem of *bolgging* here. It has nothing to do with the thread.

Comment: @Makoto: Actually it does. If you want to write a series of posts, your repeated edits is likely to be applied to *most* of them (as in your case). Had that been a single post, I am sure that almost no one would have cared - as I repeatedly claimed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I rarely edit a proof once I finished it.
Except correcting a typo.

Comment: @Makoto: Of course. But until you finish the proof... sheesh.

Comment: @AsafKaragila We are talking about whether *blogging* has anything to do with *frequent edits* or not. I say they are irrelevant.

Comment: @Makoto: This is *your* opinion. If you wish to explain it please post an answer, or start a meta thread.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are the one who bring up seemingly irrelevant topic here.
You have to explain it if you think it's relevant.

Comment: @Makoto: I explain it, you simply don't care for what I wrote. If you have a public problem with me, please start a meta thread.

Comment: @AsafKaragila As I wrote, I rarely edit a proof after I finished it. So I don't think your explanation makes sense.

Comment: Asaf: chill. Don't lower yourself to trolling. @Makoto: your repetitive response and attitude rather reminds me of a certain Monty Python sketch. Perhaps that is why so many users seem exasperated with you.

Comment: @WilleWong Trolling? I'm just saying *blogging* is a different topic. Repetitive? Because Asaf talks to me about it!

Comment: @WilleWong "Perhaps that is why so many users seem exasperated with you." So many? I know only two people who seem exasperated with me. Asaf and Arturo. I think I know why and it is not what you say.

Comment: Amazing... I really don't know what to say about that. I mean that in the most sincere way possible.

Comment: I don't think trying to convince Asaf that *blogging* is off topic is trolling.

Comment: Makoto: The fact that Arturo and Asaf have taken it upon themselves to attempt repeatedly to explain to you why your behavior is inappropriate **does not mean** they are the only two who are exasperated with you. (Consider how many downvotes you've gotten, and on posts that are in and of themselves quite worthy!!) I, for one, have upvoted many of your questions and some of your answers. That doesn't mean your behavior doesn't bother me. It simply means I'm holding out hope that you will be made to see the light in some other way. (cont.)

Comment: I will say that I am quite interested in how much can be proved without AC, and so I find your posts and endeavors to be quite worthy. As you, yourself pointed out, though, you're looking into a big question. Such a question might be better suited to MathOverflow (or a final post to ArXiv). My advice to you is: (1) be careful in your posts (fine-tune before posting, as much as possible); (2) be aware that you're part of a virtual community, here, and just as in a real-life community, reckless disregard for others will be frowned upon and (to the extent possible) punished.

Comment: Hopefully, Bill's sandbox (which I've just discovered) will be of great use to you in composing your answers while avoiding ruffling other users' feathers.