# Where is the fine line between using and misusing?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, users

***Disclaimer:*** I am fully aware that we have a no-names policy on the meta. However due to recent events I am sorry to be the one to break it on such a delicate topic. Willie [tried](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/) to do it without resorting to names, and it seems to have failed. In this thread I wish to discuss the behavior of a particular user, which is unprecedented on this site. I will do my best to avoid a judgmental tone, and to remain impartial throughout the post.

*I am asking the community members to read carefully, point out mistakes on my retelling, and suggest whether or not this behavior should be acceptable or not, and why.*

*$\qquad$- Asaf.*

---

In the past two weeks the user [Makoto Kato](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28422/) has posted over ten questions to this site. The majority of these questions were about whether or not a particular property for particular type of objects would hold without the aid of the axiom of choice.

He would go and answer most of his questions on his own, posting incomplete answers with the intention of completing them on a later occasion. Despite the repeated requests 
(see 
[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168009/lying-over-theorem-without-axiom-of-choice#comment386891_168083),
[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169889/dedekinds-theorem-on-an-integrally-closed-algebra-over-a-field-without-axiom-of#comment390685_169889),
[3](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/how-much-self-editing-is-too-much#comment17716_4613))
 that he first sit to write his answer [almost] completely and *then* post it, Makoto has dismissed this as a matter of personal taste and insisted that he was not misusing the site.

One important link is Makoto's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56454/abelian-categories-and-axiom-ab5/165375#165375) which was edited no less than **81(!)** times, of those only two edits were made by other users. Surely a record throughout the SE network. This was not his only excessive edit, and many of his posts were edited well into the CW-hammer (e.g. 
[4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161853/a-fundamental-lemma-of-lebesgue-measure-theory),
[5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159699/the-group-of-invertible-fractional-ideals-of-a-noetherian-domain-of-dimension-1),
[6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain/163069#163069),
[7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165675/constructing-a-galois-extension-field-with-galois-group-s-n/166872#166872),
[8](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164754/can-one-write-a-good-mathematical-textbook-without-proofs)). There is no arguing about the amount of effort and energy Makoto is putting into these posts, it is clearly a great amount.

Upon my suggestion that he opens a mathematical blog to post the complete proofs *there* and only put a summary alongside the link, the user replied that he once did that and only got downvoted (cf. [9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168009/lying-over-theorem-without-axiom-of-choice#comment388078_168083)). Ironically, by continuing his behavior he gets downvoted regardless to the content of his posts (I will address this issue later).

In another comment he said that the many questions he posts and answers are "*I'm trying to solve this problem:[math.stackexchange.com/questions/155392/...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155392/)
I think I solved it. But it's long. So I split it to several questions.*" (quoted from 
[10](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169889/dedekinds-theorem-on-an-integrally-closed-algebra-over-a-field-without-axiom-of#comment390641_169889) and
[11](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169889/dedekinds-theorem-on-an-integrally-closed-algebra-over-a-field-without-axiom-of#comment390643_169889)) and upon my suggestion to write a paper and post it on arXiv (see [12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169889/dedekinds-theorem-on-an-integrally-closed-algebra-over-a-field-without-axiom-of#comment390647_169889)) his reply was that it is not worth the trouble (cf. [13](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169889/dedekinds-theorem-on-an-integrally-closed-algebra-over-a-field-without-axiom-of#comment390648_169889)).

Later on, however, in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169889/) the following appears:

> **Motivation**
>   This question came from my efforts to solve [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155392/) presented by Andre Weil in 1951.
>
> Can we prove the following theorem without Axiom of Choice?
>   If the answer is affirmative, by using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170922/), we can get many examples of Dedekind domains without using Axiom of Choice.
>   [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170605/) is a related question.

In my eyes solving a problem presented by Weil is definitely a good enough topic to post on arXiv. That is a subjective opinion though, and I suppose it remains as such.

So it seems that this user decided to tackle a big problem, which is definitely encouraged, but also decided to use this website as his personal scratchpad for writing his proofs, posting partial answers and completing them later on. The result is scary: answers so long that it is impractical to read them all from a screen of a website, especially one that lacks a proper printing function (I know about the stackapp, it's worthless).

In the various links above it is visible that many of the comments calling Makoto to cease this behavior are upvoted, and the apparent number of downvotes on his various questions and answers is also an alarming sign telling us that there is a portion of the community which is very dissatisfied with this sort of behavior.

Now to address the downvoting, I agree that downvoting due to the person and not the mathematical content is a bad move. However I am also aware that it is a natural reaction of a community which cannot otherwise signal a member he is acting wrong. If a thorn is intruding the body, the immune system will react to the foreign object even at the cost of harming the body itself to some degree. Indeed it will often harm the body to signal the organism that something is wrong. In this aspect the downvotes are merely a rather violent response to Makoto's behavior and disregarding the requests of others.

I believe that this has made things worse. Today Makoto edited not one, not two, but *six* of his questions repeatedly (often in successive bursts, one after the other) and edited into each and every question the same content about his motivation, a question about the downvote (something which is often done in the comments) and lastly a link to MathOverflow he found interesting and related. This is well after [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/) has informed him that editing bumps the questions and take front page space which should be shared amongst other askers as well (see [14](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/how-much-self-editing-is-too-much#comment17623_4613)).

The latter is something I find very offensive, regardless to whether or not it is intentional. I should remark that seeing how Makoto was already informed that this is not something people appreciate on this site, it becomes an even more severe situation.

---

Now I ask, what do you, dear community members, think? Is there a misuse of the software? Should we accept someone editing a single post over 70 times within a few days? Should we allow someone to edit a bulk of his questions *repeatedly* entering the same content?

Comment: I like how someone already downvoted this before there was enough time to actually read through the whole thing and consider. It was suggested that I post a meta thread on the topic, and since there is absolutely no way of doing that without resorting to names... I resorted to names.

Comment: Asaf, it was my downvote to which you refer in your comment. Indeed I had read through your question, and although I respect you and your mathematical contributions here very much, I downvoted this question, because I disagree with the view you are advocating. Furthermore, the rude treatment of Makoto in comments to his questions is itself objectionable. Most of the questions in question are very sound, and I would urge a greater degree of tolerance. Let's all concentrate on mathematics instead of this.

Comment: Joel, thank you very much for coming forth and explaining. I agree that the rudeness in the comments is as objectionable, even more, than downvotes based on a personal reason. However I did try to be nice, most of the reaction I got was a cold and repeated "this is solely your opinion. I don't care.", I should probably add that I had a brush with Makoto before. We had argued over a comment thread in which he practically wanted me (or someone else) to reprove a book of analysis for him. I also found his reactions equally rude when he began assuming I am "opposed to these questions". (cont)

Comment: (cont) I am sure that most people on this site who know me, also know that I am probably the *last* person who would be opposed to this sort of discussion. Not to mention his continuing insistence that others telling him what to do is rude and despotic, but ignoring the requests of others is a completely reasonable and social behavior.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Answering own question has no problem in this site. Rather it is encouraged.
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @Makoto: Not once I had remarked that *this* (answering your own question) is unacceptable. You keep ignoring my point. It is unreasonable to use the site as a scratchpad and de facto post a paper on the site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why is answering one's own question unacceptable?

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you think it's *publicly* unacceptable, please open a meta thread on it.

Comment: @Makoto: **I have opened a meta thread.** You are commenting in it. *Please* stop repeating this mantra. I also repeatedly said that I think it **is acceptable** to answer you own questions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I just misread your comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila So you think answering my question is okay. So what's the problem?

Comment: @MakotoKato, answering your own question is fine. Cutting beef with a knife is fine. That doesn't mean you can run around stabbing cows. It's the fact that you violate (or nearly violate) other policies and guidelines while doing so that's the real problem.

Comment: @RobertMastragostino What exactly are the other policies and guidelines?

Comment: @MakotoKato Your questions are all quite clearly written for you, and not for us. Even when you answer your own questions, the intent should be to contribute to the knowledge of others, but what you're writing is very opaque and not especially expository. It's pretty arguably "not reasonably scoped" if it has to be split across several questions with very long answers. If you're doing research then that's fantastic, but it doesn't fit with the purposes of this particular site. Your intent doesn't seem to be community-based, so it's odd that you'd use a community-based site for such things.

Comment: @RobertMasttragostino Just because you don't understand my question well does not necessarily mean that my question is not clearly written for other people.

Comment: See, this is *why* folks are discouraged from focusing on specific users rather than issues: you're tackling 4-5 different problems here, and hence the responses you're getting tend to focus on... One of them. I don't think this discussion will be terribly productive.

Comment: @Shog: I don't know whether or not you are following the main site, but this is something that I tried to see how to tackle "globally" for a few days and I realized that such behavior was never seen on this site before, and maybe even on the SE network, and there are no "predefined" norms to adhere to. This post was *really* my last resort. Believe me.

Comment: @Asaf: your core complaint appears to be the "scratchpad" feel of these answers (at least; you keep returning to this in comments). If that's the case, you're really better off leading with that instead of the number of edits, the self-answering, the length, or the communication breakdown. I think you'll be hard-put to make a case against this behavior otherwise, simply *because* it is so rare.

Comment: @Shog: Willie tried that, not very successfully. I was trying to figure out where it failed, and this was it: it was exactly the fact that on its own, scratchpadding can be tolerated if done reasonably. In a "global" post there is hardly any appeal to the extremely unique case at hand, but rather to a global situation. See what ensued Willie's attempt and in particular how Henning and myself, two barefoot men argued until we got too tired. There was no option *but* to make it specific. From this case later on we can draw conclusions and make point-specific threads (scratchpadding, etc.).

Comment: @MakotoKato I'm fully aware that others can understand your questions and answers better than I can. My point is that you're spreading very technical answers across several questions to serve your own goals, not the math.SE community. "Opaque" doesn't mean "not understood", it means that it's a heavily condensed final result as one may find in a paper, not an explanation that would encourage understanding. Most of the problem isn't even in the initial posting (which is perfectly understandable and definitely arguable), but your refusal to listen to the suggestions of more experienced users.

Comment: @MakotoKato Your last post on AC and then subsequently answering it immediately really shows you are using this site as your own theatre for macbeth. Please stop doing it. Read the Q&A, start your own blog or whatever.

Comment: @BenjaLim I have no idea what's wrong with it. Please open a meta thread on it if you'd like to discuss it. I don't have a right to open a meta thread.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please explain what's wrong with frequent editing.

Comment: @Makoto: No. The burden of explanations has shifted onto you. It was made clear, I hope, in this thread hat your actions are outside the norm. Now you should defend them. In the time you have been active here, have you seen anyone else do it? Why did you think it was okay?

Comment: @AsafKaragila You never explained why it's wrong.

Comment: I should also point you, in case you missed it, to Robert's reply to you under JDH's answer.

Comment: Seriously? Never explained? Are kidding me?

Comment: One of the reasons why I'm writing detailed proofs is for future references.
When I answer another member's question, I may be able to refer it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If I missed it, I apologize. Would you please explain again?

Comment: @MakotoKato In a medium where the entire conversation has been written down, and you get notifications for every single reply, how can you honestly say that you "missed it"? You have access to *everything we've ever said about it*. If there's a specific point that needs clarification, quote it and explain what you don't understand. Since you're on a Q&A site you should understand how that works and why we say you're not cooperating. Stop being obtuse. This filibustering is blatant and childish. I'll repeat: argue maturely and make a decent case, or stop.

Comment: "Cutting beef with a knife is fine. That doesn't mean you can run around stabbing cows." - damn, @Robert, I quite like that metaphor. I'll be stealing it, if it's alright with you.

Comment: @J.M. A compliment from J.M.! (faints)

Comment: FWIW: for me, the "If you think it's publicly unacceptable, please open a meta thread on it." comment **on an actual, genuine, honest-to-goodness meta thread** is a very telling piece of behavior. I have to wonder if the obstinacy being displayed by this user is of the willful sort, or is merely due to said user's inability to pick up on subtle (though at this point, we are being as subtle as a grenade) cues/hints to modify his behavior.

Comment: @J.M. It seems that you missed his next comment where he says "I just misread your comment. Sorry about that". Thus it seems that he was referring to a creating a *new* meta thread on the *separate* topic of self-answered questions. So your prior comment is a bit unfair, considering that it is based on a misunderstanding. Perhaps you would consider deleting it and reposting it to reflect more accurately what transpired.

Comment: @MakotoKato Are you for real? What are you trying to do? Are you trolling around with me asking me to open a meta thread? What is this thread here?

Comment: @Bill: since I can't edit the comment anymore, you could consider removing everything before "I have to wonder..." Still, I would have thought it glaringly visible that this current thread is in meta, but I'll go with your more charitable take on the matter for the time being.

Comment: @J.M. But doing that might alter the meaning of the votes, which are possibly based on the misunderstanding. Why not simply delete it (and repost another version if need be)?

Comment: @Bill: Seeing how Makoto used that mantra several times, even after Willie did make an attempt to open the first thread, I'm not sure at all that Makoto fully understands the role of meta, or the role of this thread.

Comment: More of a trivium than an actual point, but in the current database dumps (Jun 27 '12) there are only 49  among roughly 150k posts with (strictly) more than 20 edits. At least that's what [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/52795/) on data.SE tells me.

Comment: @t.b. I made a slight modification to show the user name as well. The query can be found [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/75452).

Comment: @Asaf That query is not correctly counting revisions. For example it lists 30 edits by GarouDan to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74074) but in fact there are only 13 edits by GarouDan and one edit each by 3 other users. Compare to [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/75407) by Shog9, which lists 12 edits by GarouDan.

Comment: @t.b. See my prior comment.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for pointing that out (good thing I added a disclaimer...). I don't consider these latest statistical comments to be very important, so it would be fine with me to just delete them altogether or replace them by a single comment linking to Shog9's query which is probably more trustworthy. If I understand Shog9's script correctly, there have only been 82 posts overall that crossed the automatic CW-ification limit, so that only reinforces the feeling that "over-editing" (for whatever reason) happens rather rarely.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila As someone pointed out, you should post only one question in a thread.
Please choose one of the problems and open a thread on it.
Of course, you can post other questions, but only one at each time.

Comment: @Makoto: What answer? Please explain. And as 25 people voted joriki's answer seem to agree, the issue here is exactly one where each problem on its own is somewhat harmless, but *you* seem to have combined them all into what most people on this page agree is a misuse of the site.

Comment: @Bill: The query you linked shows a worse picture. Out of 11 threads that were edited at least 20 times by the poster, 4 are by Makoto, making his action even further out of the norm.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "What answer?" What's wrong with frequent editing?

Comment: @Makoto: Taking front page space is *not* a good enough answer? Even after being expressed as a major problem b *several* people?? Do you bother to read what others wrote, or do you just repeat the mantra "open a meta thread" and "please explain."?

Comment: @AsafKaragila "Taking front page space is not a good enough answer?".
No, because you have never mentioned it to me.
Apparently you have a different reason.
I'm asking what it is.

Comment: @Makoto: How did you deduce that? Please explain.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You never complained it to me. So it cannot be the main reason.

Comment: I'm sorry, but after seeing the last few comments of the user in question, I am going to have to abandon Bill's take and go back to my opinion that the user is being willfully obstinate. The user does not also seem to understand the notion of "unwritten rules", and will thus keep breaching other people's sensibilities since there is nothing written that prohibits his behavior. No country has a law explicitly stating that "you shouldn't be a jerk"; that doesn't imply you can go around being a jerk...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think Makoto is just trolling you now. His last few comments clearly show traits of trolling - he has already been informed ***multiple*** times that his behaviour is breaching community norms. He has already been ***told*** that his behaviour of constantly crowding the front page is selfish. Makoto if you continue to dodge the issues at hand and act like that, I would not be surprised if you were to get a suspension. And by the way what I have said is not a threat because I ***cannot*** initiate it.

Comment: @Asaf The queries on edit counts are not of much help here since they reveal nothing temporal. Many edits by itself may not be a problem, depending on the timespan, e.g. another user made 80 edits to a question but, afaik, there were no comments or meta threads about that. The issue is not about extreme editing in general but, rather, about a very particular style of extreme editing.

Comment: @Bill: Allow me to repeat this *again*. If Makoto would have edited only one post (or two) that often, no one would have cared. In fact, people would probably appreciate him for putting that much effort and energy in that. However doing that in *most* of his posts is not a normative practice, and ignoring *all* the requests to stop that is bordering in antisocial behavior.

Comment: @Asaf Perhaps you misunderstood my prior comment. It was in response to your prior 'worse picture' comment, about queries on on *total edit counts*. It says nothing about the points that you 'repeat *again*'.

Comment: Perhaps the process for 'bumping' a question should be modified, so that bumping occurs randomly, with the chance of bumping (inversely) related to recent density of edits?

Answer (score 54):

I just spent quite a bit of time reading through all the comments in this thread and [Willie's](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612). A lot of them jump back and forth between various issues, and they have a very controversial feel to them, but it seems to me that on the important issues there's a rather broad consensus, and I want to try to distill that here.

Asking questions with the intention of contributing to the site by answering them oneself is explicitly encouraged. Editing answers to improve them is constructive. Posting partial answers to share work in progress and avoid needless duplication of efforts is OK.

However, from these three statements it doesn't follow that posting partial answers to one's own questions and then editing them a lot is welcome. The rationale for posting partial answers to other people's questions is to avoid duplication of effort – if I can answer a large part of the question, or solve an important case, or find a proof but can't fill a gap in it, or am waiting for my computer to complete a search for counterexamples overnight, I'll post rather than letting someone else do the same work over again; if I can later solve other cases or fill the gap or find a counterexample, I'll edit the answer.

When I'm answering my own question, on the other hand, I'm in control of the entire process. There's no reason to hurry; I can prepare the question and the answer at leisure and post them when I'm satisfied with them. Of course I might still spot typos after I posted, or have some new ideas later and add them, or respond to comments; the point is merely that there's no reason to post when I already *know* that I will probably want to edit the answer again soon. It was this very specific behaviour that was at the core of what Asaf, in my view rightly, objected to.

As was stated in the comments, editing comes at a cost, the cost of space on the default main page. Everyone should use that scarce public good responsibly. That involves trade-offs  that can't be formalized in rules. Posting a partial answer that goes a long way towards answering the question is OK; posting a rudimentary sketch and then editing it several dozen times, one detail at a time, isn't; and the "fine line between using and misusing" runs somewhere in between. We can't pinpoint it in the abstract; respecting it will always involve responsible decisions; but its exact location certainly depends on whether one is answering someone else's question or one's own. Most commenters seemed to agree that in the present specific case it was crossed.

Comment: Beautifully put, especially the last paragraph.

Comment: +1ed. Do you plan to apply for moderatorship of this site?

Comment: @did and to everyone who upvoted that comment: Thanks very much, I appreciate the encouragement. I hadn't seriously considered it because there are already too many demands on my time as it is, but I promise I'll think about it when it's time for the next elections :-)

Comment: There's still time left. An hour or so, but still... :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks for the reminder :-) I did seriously consider it, and I would have nominated myself if I'd had the impression that there weren't enough candidates who would do a good job. My contributions to math.SE have become more intermittent recently, and I hesitated to take on a commitment because my other commitments have been growing. I would have done it if it had seemed necessary to preserve good moderation of the site, but I don't flatter myself to think that I'm indispensible in view of the current roster of candidates :-)

Answer (score 36):

My opinion is that this kind of dramatic spectacle, especially when it has a personal nature as here, is harmful to the site. This goes both for this meta question as well as the rude comments on the questions in question.

I would urge that we concentrate on mathematics. Answer the questions if you find them interesting, and ignore them if you don't.

Who cares if someone makes a lot of edits? Making dozens of edits in the space of a few hours has the same effect, in terms of keeping the question on the main page, as making one or two in the same time frame. And the quality of some of the answers we are speaking about is rather high.

I suggest simply that we be more tolerant.

---

Meanwhile, a note to Makoto: it seems that your style of answering is irritating some people. Why not try to accommodate that perspective, and reduce your frequency of edits?

Comment: Joel, thank you for the answer. I again appreciate your input. I do not think this can be ignored so easily. When a would gets as deep as four downvotes on a reasonable question, simply because the OP is acting in a particular way... this is a sign that things have gone far enough to require an open discussion to excise the problem and iron the problems. If we could ignore these things, it would be great. Unfortunately, it's hard to ignore some things. It feels to me that Makoto is unreachable via words, and there are only so many of them I can use before feeling frustrated. (cont)

Comment: (...) I have enough frustration from mathematical problems which insist on not being solved, and adding more from an online persona which insists on ignoring my requests when they are civilized and forces me deeper into this argument which I do not like... this makes me feel like something is fundamentally wrong here. So we end up with downvotes, meta threads, and closing votes.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  It may not always be *easy* to ignore such behavior, but it is often beneficial.  No one has been *forced* into argument with Makoto.

Comment: @Jonas: It is in the nature of some people to argue. You can say that no one was forced to live in the street as a protest for two months. No one was forced to rebel in 1776 and 1789. No one was forced to rebel when the Catholics and the Protestants broke off. Well, in all these examples, I mean of course the very beginning... when the war broke people had to survive of course. My point is that some people have it in their nature to stand up against what they perceive as wrong. Maybe not always, maybe not in every context. But in some context... and one can't go against his own nature for long

Comment: @Asaf: I find your comment to be interesting reading, but much too dramatic applied to the case at hand.  This is a mathematics Q&A website, not a cultural revolution.

Comment: @Jonas: I agree. I have a habit of slight dramatization. My point remains, though. I can't resist these things for too long. In Makoto's case I tried but eventually I just couldn't. Have you seen that thread I argued with WM about the invalidity of his argument over 60 comments? :-)

Comment: I pretty much agree with the answer and above comments, but I would like to request Makoto to just write up his answers and put them on ArXiV, where they belong.

Comment: Also, @Jonas, [Math is the next revolution!](http://news.harvard.edu/gazette/2001/05.17/e04-moses.html) :-)

Comment: @JDH Actually I'm making my edits less frequently.

Comment: @JohannesKloos I'm an amateur. Mathematics is my hobby. I'm not interested in ArXiV.

Comment: Then start a blog. I am certain that you got yourself a crowd of people interested in what you have to say. I just don't think that you should be using MSE to de facto publish your results. And this is essentially what you are doing right now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You seem to forget something very important. There are usually several(or many) answers to a question. If I post a question, I may get several answers which may be better than mine.

Comment: Yes, you may. You should also remember that if you write a blog you can allow people to comment. If you write consistently, clearly and well the crowd of your readers will grow with time, perhaps even quickly. Those readers are the same people who would and could answer your questions. As they stand, it is nearly impossible and most improbable that someone will sit through reading [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/170688) which contains numerous links to even longer answers. If you write it cleanly and in a readable format, I'm sure someone will be able to read and comment better.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think I would have more chances to get good answers here. Moreover, good answers here would serve as the members' benefits.

Comment: @Makoto: Judging by the current distribution of votes there seems to be somewhat of a disagreement over this subject. It seems that this is your opinion, and it's fine, but it seems that others disagree. As I told you before: you have damaged your image and now you have to work twice as hard to correct the damage. This is now *your move* and you cannot rid this by suggesting to open a meta thread, or by claiming this is a matter of opinion. This is no longer and opinion. The flood of downvotes your posts have been drowning in is a very proof of this, and the sooner you get this, the better.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe most of the downvotes were made by personal preferences. This is simply not right. Votes should be made for a mathematical content.

Comment: @Makoto: I referred to this issue in my post. Yes, it seems highly likely that the votes were made based on a personal grudge. It shouldn't be that way, but this is only because you were *repeatedly* asked to change your behavior, and all you did was wave off the arguments as subjective and unjustified. If you are not willing to play by the social rules, why should others keep them with you? Why should they respect the social rule that says that voting is based on content? This is merely a reaction to your behavior, why are you acting so surprised?

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you are implying that I'm not following the social rules, please explain.

Comment: @Makoto: Implying? Oh no, no no. I've been telling you that flat out for a whole week now. I have a whole post up in the top of this very page which says that you are not following the social norms of this site. Whenever I told you that, your reply was that it is my opinion and you don't really want to discuss that with me... reading that, are you *really* surprised that people downvoted you for no mathematical reason?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I repeat: Please explain.

Comment: @Makoto: All that post above in a comment box? Seems a bit hard to do. But okay. Myself and others have asked you to go easy on editing. No one told you not to answer your own questions nor to stop asking questions. It was requested that you simply slow down, think it through on your own *before* starting the post. Then, after you have finished, post an answer *once* and customize it later. Instead of agreeing, or giving a reasonable reply your answers implied you truly believe that this is how the site works, but it's not. It's a community law in these sites, (cont.)

Comment: I kindly request that further discussion of this topic be carried out on someone's blog.

Comment: (cont.) and this is not the way *this* particular community intended to use the software. You broke the rules. When you were engaged, again, by members you again rode it off as a subjective opinion and completely disregarded anyone else's opinion on *how to use the site*. Mathematically, there was no problem with your questions (except the constant philosophical conundrum people see when someone floods with questions on choice), but your high rate of questions with high rate of edits were [are] unacceptable, and you were given several remarks on that.

Comment: @MakotoKato Please understand that none of us are stupid. Either argue your point maturely ("I intended $x$, what about it makes you think $y$?", not "Please explain yourself yet again, I don't understand but refuse to explain my confusion properly") Or stop.

Comment: @JDH: I'm sorry. We'll stop (here, at least). I'll point out that currently you're the one with the blog. Rest assured, though, we are not going to take it there! :-)

Comment: Thanks, Asaf, and I hope you don't take my remarks on this topic to detract from our friendly interaction on all other topics! -Joel

Comment: @JDH You make some good points, but the statement "Making dozens of edits in the space of a few hours has the same effect, in terms of keeping the question on the main page, as making one or two in the same time frame" is somewhat misleading. The questions that get the most attention by far (in my experience) are those visible without scrolling. On my laptop, that's the top 3 questions, and on most computers it might be as many as the top 5. But the top 5 were all updated in the last 10min! So frequent editing makes a big difference.

Comment: @MakotoKato, you write «Votes should be made for a mathematical content» but that is not a correct statement: this is not a online mathematical journal we are talking about, but essentially a social site whose subject is mathematics. Votes reflect the perceived mathematical value of the content, the value of the contribution to the community and, why not, an evaluation of the behaviour of posters. It's quite imaginable that people may be at times simultaneously incredibly obnoxious *and* mathematically correct, and there is no reason why votes should not reflect that, if voters are so inclined

Comment: @Mariano I  disagree. In my opinion one should strive *not* to downvote posts based on user behavior, since this sends very misleading messages to the community. Readers seeing such downvotes  may make false inferences such as: the content is incorrect, off-topic, too elementary, too advanced,  etc. Instead, problems with user behavior are better addressed via flags, meta posts, etc.

Comment: This reminds me of Jordan's 15 minutes of meta fame.

Comment: @Bill, when someone comes up with an academic jornal based on user votes, I might possibly agree with your opinion as it would apply there. Of course, it is true that people may make false inferences based on their interpreting votes incorrectly: that should be fixed by making it clear to new-comers (as soon as people stay on the site for a while it should be obvious to them...) that votes on posts are not a measure of mathematical correctness or even value, not by declring that votes mean something different than they do! People have wrongly interpreted pretty much anything, in any case...

Comment: Of course, you are free to strive to whatever it is you personally want to strive!

Answer (score 15):

I think there is a wide range of acceptable behavior and I appreciate it when someone helps another user by giving an extensive and detailed answer, even if it takes 81 edits. The ability to edit posts is IMHO meant to improve the quality of posts to the readers of MSE. I do think the 81 edits served that goal and were perfectly legitimate.

I think it is *not* appropriate to use the edit function to make comments and use it as a means of discussing, such as has apparently happened [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170234/nilpotency-of-the-jacobson-radical-of-an-artinian-ring-without-axiom-of-choice). I think this is not a legitimate use since it takes a scarce ressource, "attention for active posts", away from other users and there are means such as commenting that don't.

So there is a cost of making an edit and one sometimes has to judge whether the benefits outweigh the costs. If one is planning on posting a question in order to answer it oneself, it shows respect for other users to prepare the answer well enough that not many edits are necessary that take away the scarce ressource and I would encourage everyone to do so. Even if the contributions are of a very high mathematical quality, one should take into account that M.SE is open to all mathematical levels and specialized questions may be of interest to only a very small part of the communiy.

Whether it is legitimate to use M.SE as a mathematical sketchpad is a very different question and should be discussed in a different thread. I'm pretty sure that there exists no norm for this so far. But I would like to point out that the [existing rationale](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) for answering ones own questions doesn't really apply here. These are not the kind of questions people will look up at MSE.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker "But I would like to point out that the existing rationale for answering ones own questions doesn't really apply here."
May I ask the reason?

Comment: @MakotoKato: The usual rationale seems to be that this should be used for questions and answers useful to many users, while your problem seems to be quite specialized. I think this [post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) on the SE blog is even more explicit.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker It says:
"Since Stack Overflow launched, we've been trying to explain that it's not just a Q&A platform: it's also a place where you can publish things that you've learned: recipes, FAQs, HOWTOs, walkthroughs, and even bits of product documentation, as long you format it as a question and answer"

I think this is exactly what I'm doing.
Even if my question is specialized(I don't think so, though), what's wrong with it?

Comment: @MakotoKato: There is nothing wrong with it, but if it is very specialized, I think it would be good if you made an effort to avoid bumping it too often with edits. Contentwise, I'm not competent to judge. But I would certainly prefer something that I'm interested in and that I'm competent in to be presented as a downloadable and printable paper. I'm not sure anyone but you is following your whole argument now.

Comment: @Michael Please keep in mind that Math.SE does not discriminate in any way against particular mathematical topics, no matter how specialized. fyi: at least a few (distinguished) members have remarked that they found such topics of interest (as do I).

Comment: @Bill: I'm not against advanced questions in any field. I do think that the main point of the encouragement to post ones own questions is to get more canonical answers to frequent questions by, say, writing about a general method. And I do think the mode of presentation is more problematic than the topic. I think following the whole argument involves some 40 Lemmas or more as of now.

Comment: @Michael Note that SE [explicitly encourages](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) blog-like publishing that fits into the Q&A format. Makoto has [already mentioned](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/where-is-the-fine-line-between-using-and-misusing/4654#comment17778_4653) that he will be making edits less frequently, so the problem may be solved.

Comment: @Bill: I am not sure that MSE should be used for blogging on *advanced* topics. These things may benefit greatly on a separate site rather than on a site where they get very very little exposure.

Comment: @Asaf Our charter is to welcome *all* questions on mathematics, both elementary *and advanced,* both pure and applied, both in-fashion and out-of-fashion, etc. In short, we do *not* discriminate.

Comment: @Bill: There is a vast difference between asking a question, and posting a Q&A-blog via this site. I am only opposed to posting a *blog* and only about advanced topics. I feel that it is not in the interest of the site nor it is in the interest of the blog.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you mean by posting a blog?

Comment: @BillDubuque, indeed, Makoto has already mentioned that he weill be making edits less frequently. http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/171395/revisions

Comment: @Mariano That's *good* news, since it is $82$ revisions *fewer* than [one post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4626/242) by a different user.

Comment: Yes, that is the approach that is going to help with this situation. Good.

Comment: @Mariano Was your penultimate comment part of an "approach that is going to help with this situation"?

Comment: Yes. It consists in evaluating how people put into practice what they have said they wil do.

Comment: @Makoto: Please explain what do you mean by "What do you mean by posting a blog?". I figured it was rather self-explanatory.

Comment: @Asaf Makoto is not the only member puzzled by your remark about "blogging on *advanced* topics". Since that is orthogonal to your main point of "scratchpad" style composition of posts, perhaps it would be best to concentrate here *only* on this primary point, to void any further bifurcation and confusion.

Comment: @Bill: When having a discussion on a certain problem, several others may appear as tangents. I am sure that from your years of experience you already know that. I suggested that a blogging-like use of MSE is not the proper use, at least in this particular case. In the comments you have asserted that SE encourages a blog-like posting of Q&A. You should heed your own advice, if you wish to stick to the main point. My point about blogging advanced topics is that 99.99% of advanced questions here are lost amidst the sea of homework, (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) and it is not in the interest of neither the blogger nor the reader to navigate this sea. Furthermore, Makoto's posts now form a tangled web of lemmata, definitions and theorems all of which are non-standard (or else he would not have had to put them in his answers and questions). This means that if I want to sit down and follow his arguments to the letter I have to start roaming between answers and questions and eventually write it cleanly in one or two parts. *This* is something that would benefit from being in a blog, where data can be clearly presented.

Comment: And of course, lest we forget that *some* of the questions are linked to others but if I am a visitor unfamiliar with the software and I stumbled upon [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170234/) I would have no idea that it is all just a big part of this major scheme to prove some grand problem by Weil that will be able to further the work in constructive commutative algebra, nor I will know about the lengthly threads of the poster.

Comment: @Makoto, Bill: I hope that it has been established that the act of tackling a big problem, especially one whose solution requires *several* questions and answers, on the pages of this site is an act of blogging. This is something better suited to a mathematical blog in which a certain post (or several) describe, and attempts to solve a problem. In fact this is much much better as an expository paper to be posted on arXiv or even published, but that is besides the point.

Comment: @Asaf Of course if you bring up such tangential topics then readers will feel obliged to add corrections, etc. Both here and in Willie's thread, I and others (e.g. Shog9) have emphasized that the tangents are suffocating the primary point. Alas, once again, there are too many intermingled issues here to judge what the voting reflects. For this and others reasons, it is usually works best to focus on *one* issue per meta thread. Related threads can be linked as need be.

Comment: @Bill: I disagree with you. I think that you are trying too hard to isolate and quantify things here. This is *exactly* what both joriki and Michael have said in their posts. For each point individually, there is no real objection (and behold how Willie's thread ended up, especially Henning's answer). However when combined the problem arises. To build on Robert's analogy, no one objects to cutting beef with a knife, and no one objects to killing cows for food. If you run around the field, stabbing cows and eating them on the spot, you are likely to end up in a padded room.

Comment: @Asaf Again, I emphasize that we do *not* discriminate here based on such matters. Whether a question/answer is long or short,  isolated or dependent on a web of supporting posts, etc. plays no role in topicality decisions here. If you dislike certain types of questions or answers then it is your prerogative to ignore them. But it is not your prerogative to force your preferences upon other users. So please stop trying to do so.

Comment: @Bill: I am not forcing anyone to do anything. The point of blogging on site was raised by others, not by me. I merely suggested that a blog would be better suited for the topic. I *do* agree that there is a certain aspect of blogging in Makoto's posts, and I think that the MSE format makes it nearly impossible for anyone not within the set $\{\rm Makoto\ Kato\}$ to understand the proofs he posted in full without essentially copying/rewriting it into a place where these can be presented linearly and orderly. (...)

Comment: (cont.) I also pointed out that such blogging-like activities whose focus is advanced (in comparison to basic cardinal arithmetics, basic integration and such) are in fact losing quite a lot by being posted this way here. I did not suggest that we forbid, downvote, or agree not to post these things. Your words tell me that you have an idea about how I feel on Makoto's use of the site, and you project it into anything I write on this page. Please stop doing that, you are a moderator and you must transcend beyond this to be able an exercise judgment when needed.

Comment: @Asaf Do you *really* think that old-fashioned *linearly* ordered media (papers/books) make it *easier* to traverse a complex web of proofs? One of the primary *advantages* of the web is that it sets us free from the chains that bound us to linearly-presented expositions, enabling us to present results in a shape that more naturally reflects innate structure. Why do you consider that a *disadvantage*?  If you have difficulties traversing webs of related posts then I highly recommend that you spend some time investigating software tools for such. The rewards will be great.

Comment: @Asaf I'm not "projecting" anything, I'm merely responding to what you write here. As I stressed, by conflating many of the issues you are making it much harder for readers to understand your points.

Comment: @Bill: Please teach me how to read more than one thing at once. I'm sorry but I am an old-fashioned guy. My brain can process only one piece of text at a time. If I feel the need to jump back and forth in a paper or a book, I do that. If I feel the need to open several papers at once, I do that. I cannot, however, *read* more than one thing at the same time.

Comment: What Makoto did was essentially to write *one* proof over several posts. That would be *one* thing. I prefer to have *one* thing in *one* linear presentation.

Comment: I wonder why some people are objecting fiercely against "blogging" or "publishing". Maybe they are in a wrong place: "Since Stack Overflow launched, we've been trying to explain that it's not just a Q&A platform: it's also a place where you can publish things that you've learned: recipes, FAQs, HOWTOs, walkthroughs, and even bits of product documentation, as long you format it as a question and answer." http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: @MakotoKato Read the FAQ.

Comment: @MakotoKato: The FAQ says "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an *entire* book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." I'm pretty sure it is not intended to ask for the book chapter by chapter.

Comment: @MakotoKato Do you understand the words that are being said in this thread? If you don't I can type in indonesian/french if that helps.

Comment: @MakotoKato I can scrape by in Italian if that suits you better. And no one is against blogging and publishing. In fact that's *exactly* what was suggested. *You* are the one who's against it. I wonder why you're objecting so fiercely as well. And by your logic I can paste an entire wikipedia page as an answer, so long as I ask a question first. You know full well that you can't apply written rules without thinking like that.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I don't think the question presented by Weil has an scope of an entire book.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155392/existence-of-valuation-rings-in-an-algebraic-function-field-of-one-variable

Comment: @Robert: I think that Makoto is trying to suggest that blogging on the site, and publishing new results on the site is a good idea. However, Makoto, in mathematics it is valuable when you can cite results in further works. While arXiv has enough reputation in the community to be a good source for citations, math.SE (or MO) is not that reputable yet. One can cite it, but I believe that one cannot "depend" on results from this site without reproving them. If you honestly wish this result to be useful, you should seriously consider uploading it to arXiv.

Comment: @Makoto: I think that all your work, alongside one or two examples can fill a good chapter in a book on this topic. This is not the first time your questions have "a scope of an entire book" too. See my previous comment too please.

Comment: @Makoto You [mentioned](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/where-is-the-fine-line-between-using-and-misusing/4654#comment17778_4653) that you'd be making your edits less frequently. However, you just made 4 minor edits to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/171739/242) in a 20 minute timespan. Those edits should have been coalesced into a single edit, to be less disruptive. It is *essential* that you work towards composing your posts in a manner that is not disruptive towards other users.

Comment: @BillDubuque Still I think I'm making my edits less than before *on the whole*.
Please tell me how many is too many.

Comment: @Makoto It is good that you are trying, but you need to do better. I don't understand why you didn't submit the above-said edits as a single edit vs. 4 edits. Why is that?

Comment: @BillDubuque Please make a *public* rule on the frequency of edits. I'll follow it, of course.

Comment: @Makoto There are no written rules on such matters. It would be impossible to attempt to specify all of the possibilities, exceptions, etc, just as it would be impossible to attempt to precisely specify what is rude or anti-social behavior. I am trying to help you solve this problem in a way that will be optimal for all. If you can learn to slightly modify your editing behavior so to coalesce your edits, then this problem will be solved, and we can all get back to mathematics. Please make your best effort to do so.

Comment: @Makoto: You are **impossible**. There are *unwritten* laws that one learns by observing the community and by *listening* to experienced users. **Several** people have asked you to post only complete answers and edit minor typos and corrections if needed. Instead you disregarded all those requests and you demand written rules. Please, *stop* being antisocial.

Comment: @BillDubuque "Why is that?" Because I don't have a latex editor. I'm an amateur. Mathematics is just my hobby.

Comment: Actually I hadn't known how to write latex before I became a member of this site 3 months ago.

Comment: @Makoto What does this have to do with tex editors? Please explain why you could not wait till the last edit in said batch of 4 edits before submitting it. Why did you feel the need to make 3 incremental submits every 5 minutes on average? Be aware that SE saves drafts of your posts, so that you do not need to do so by submitting incremental edits (to protect against crashes).

Comment: I'm an old man. When I was young, there were no personal computers, lert alone latex.

Comment: @Makoto: You seem to have a computer now. Please install texlive or MikTeX (depending on your operating system) as well a LaTeX editor such as the free (and open source) Texmaker. You can work in the comfort of your own computer before posting things online.

Comment: @Bill "What does this have to do with tex editors?" Have you posted your long answer without an editor? How do you edit usually?

Comment: @Asaf But that's an orthogonal issue. Let's concentrate on determining why he is hitting the "post" button so frequently. Perhaps it has something to do with his environment, e.g. MathJax becoming garbled in Chrome, or some such.

Comment: My OS is Windows XP.

Comment: I use IE as a browser.

Comment: @Makoto Ok, is it because the answers are so *long* that it makes it difficult to use the MathJax preview? If so, how does posting incremental edits fix that? If we can understand what motivates you to post these incremental edits then perhaps we can find a workaround.

Comment: Makoto, yes. I have posted a very long answer without an editor. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172163/noetherian-condition-on-the-ring-of-formal-power-series-without-axiom-of-choice#comment395587_172163) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-are-the-axiom-of-choice-and-axiom-of-determinacy/52591#52591) (where the edits followed the discussion in the comments), and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28145/axiom-of-choice-and-automorphisms-of-vector-spaces/29469#29469) of which every revision was written into the site in one sitting.

Comment: @Bill "If so, how does posting incremental edits fix that?" I didn't analize the reason but I think definately incremental edits are easier. What's MathJax?

Comment: @Makoto When you edit your answers, is the TeX rendered in the preview window, or do you see raw TeX code? Aha, I think you are incrementally posting your answer only to get TeX rendered, because MathJax is not working. What version of IE do you use?

Comment: @Makoto MathJax is a version of LaTeX that runs in the browser. It renders TeX on-the-fly as you type it, so you can see a live preview of your TeX before you post the answer, updated with every character you type. Could you please confirm that TeX is not typeset in your preview window. Are you posting your answers frequently so you can see the rendered TeX code?

Comment: @Bill I can see the TeX in the preview window. Still incremental edits are a lot easier.

Comment: @Bill Now I understand what MathJax is. It works on my computer.

Comment: @Makoto Ok, then why are incremental edits easier? We need to know that in order to help you. Why is it easier to click "post" 4 times every 5 minutes vs. once in 20 minutes?

Comment: @BillDubuque Usually you write a small part of a long proof at one time and save it and do something else, right? If you post it, it's easier to check later.

Comment: @Makoto: Is it *that* harder to click *Start* and the *Run* and then type in `notepad` then paste the partial progress into the window and click *Save as...* and save this as a text file, and when you wish to continue simply open the text file, copy-paste into an answer box and continue until you have to stop - and if you haven't finished, copy back into the text file *instead* of posting.

Comment: The above method is pretty much how *I* do it when I have to write long answers and I feel that I should do that in parts. It is not *a lot* harder for the writer, and it is *a lot* easier for the rest of the community to deal with.

Comment: @Asaf I'm not you. I don't think my pattern of writing a proof is the same as yours.

Comment: @Makoto Please concentrate on the example at hand. We are discussing 4 edits made roughly every 5 minutes. Why did you post those 4 edits once every 5 minutes, instead of when they were all done, 20 minutes later? Nothing you have said explains this.

Comment: @BillDubuque Okay, let me see. I was thinkg hard about the proof(I didn't come up with the proof when I asked it, though I was almost certain I could prove it). So when I thought I could prove it, I posted it. Then soon after, I found it was not sufficient. So I corrected it. But then I found a better proof. So I corrected it. I also found a few typos.

Comment: Here is a suggestion: take a piece of paper, you know... one that is made out of trees, and write down your post. Let it sit for a day and see if you can significantly improve that. When you are done, write it into the site. This is what I do long before I begin typing partial answers into a text editor. I hope this is old-fashion enough for you to accept as a reasonable approach.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Long time ago, I did that. But I don't think I can go back to that.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for the explanation. But I still don't understand why you had to click the "post" button every 5 minutes. Why not let it sit in your browser, waiting for future edits, till a point when you are done for the morning, afternoon, or evening? I often leave drafts of my answers in browser windows for days (sometimes weeks or months), till I have time to complete them.

Comment: @Bill "I often leave drafts of my answers in browser windows for days (sometimes weeks or months), till I have time to complete them."

I often have to reboot my PC because it dosen't work well. I don't trust my PC.

Comment: I think I can solve the problem *partly* if I have a good *free* latex editor which runs on Windows XP and is compatible with this site.

Comment: @Makoto **Proposed Solution:** We could create a "sandbox" thread on meta that is dedicated to composing drafts of long answers. Anyone can post "drafts" of long answers there as frequently as they like. Being only one thread, many bumps aren't disruptive. You'll rarely lose work that way, since, the drafts, being genuine answers, are saved on SE servers. Occasionally, when your draft stabilizes, you copy it from meta to your main answer. Perhaps you also link your main answer to the evolving draft on meta, to solicit collaboration. Would that solve all your problems?

Comment: @Bill Sounds good. Let me try it and see.

Comment: @Makoto I created the [Sandbox for drafts of long, complex answers.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/242) Please try it out and provide feedback as need be.

Comment: @Bill, +100, were it possible. Let's hope it works.

Comment: @Bill I used it. It's okay so far. Thanks.

Comment: @Bill, nice solution! Hopefully we're back to a peaceful state...

Comment: @J.M. Peaceful, as opposed to pieceful.

Comment: @cardinal The goal was to map *pieceful* answers $\to$ *peaceful* answers!

Comment: @J.M. You're right on the money again (see above)

Comment: @Bill: And it's a wonderful solution you've proposed. I love the creativeness of it, in case that was not apparent. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Math.SE is not a personal blog, it's a community.  The front page is a disaster, and meta is full of threads about this.  If this one user refuses to take one of the many suggestions made by well respected community members, then he is trolling all of us.

If nothing else gets through to this one user, then we should threaten to ban him.  Maybe that will get through.

Comment: I think you'll find that he has been using the sandbox provided for getting things into shape before posting.

Comment: @MattCalhoun All the problems the OP was complaining were completely solved a week ago. In short, the thread is over.

Comment: @Makoto: Huh? I was complaining on *one* thing, your complete lack of disregard of any unwritten rules and social conventions in this community. No, the issue has not been solved, and you still have troubles understanding that some of the guidelines cannot be quantified into cases. The fact that there are more than one meta thread **directly** concerning your behavior, and that the most recent one is not even a week old, should be a hint that the problem is far from over.

Comment: @Makoto: I have started a thread. **You are reading and writing in it right now.** Please stop suggesting people to open meta threads whenever you wish to ignore them. Instead, take the day off mathematics and browse a bit to see how the rest of the users behave, read some comments that were left, or try to analyze posting patterns. Maybe then you will understand why this thread has a single complaint written in it.

Comment: @MakotoKato, I kindly request that you stop repeating that. I find it *impossible* to believe that you are not trolling.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I deleted it as you wish.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please tell me what exactly it is, the unwritten rule I'm disregarding.