# Editing a post for activity

Tags: discussion, editing

Is it acceptable to edit a post (adding a random comma, adding more spaces, etc.) just for the sake of activity?

It could be used to draw more attention to the post since it comes to the top of the home page because of the edit. But isn't this (exploiting the system for personal gain) unfair?

What could be done to prevent this?

Comment: No, it is not okay to do this. But be careful before assuming you know what another's motive is.

Comment: Well Im not saying that I want to do this. I just made this post because theres no other i could find on meta on this specific topic

Comment: It seems to me that some of the "related" posts (shown to the right on the desktop site) for this Question would answer your concerns.  Cf. [How much (self) editing is too much?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/how-much-self-editing-is-too-much?rq=1) and [How much bumping is too much?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-much-bumping-is-too-much?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minor edits are generally discouraged. If every person who make minor edits all the time until they got an answer to satisfy them, the site would be an even bigger mess.

As far as infractions of community norms go, this is a low one. I wouldn't even bother flagging it if it happens once or twice. Perhaps a comment letting the OP know that this is not a great way to conduct themselves is enough.

If, however, a user exhibits a pattern, or makes a lot of minor edits to a post, it is a good thing to leave a comment, and if that doesn't help, escalate to us via the flags.